# How to round products price?

Tags: magento-1.9, price, price-rules, rounding

I have installed Price Rounding plugin to my Magento site.

It works good, but I need to round price like that:
131.26 -> 131.25

The plugin gives me that:
131.26 -> 131.00

I know that it uses PHP math functions, but I don't know is there some PHP math functions that can give me 131.25 result.

Maybe there is another way to round price?

Comment: Rounding 131.26 to 131.25 is not rounding. Are you sure that's what you want to achieve ? Seems very unusual to simply remove 1 cent of a price just like this.

Comment: Yes, that it what I need

Comment: Hi, check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239600/rounding-up-to-the-second-decimal-place

Answer (score 1):

To round prices as .00 .25 0.50  0.75 you can use the following function:

```
function round_quarter($price){
  return round($price * 4) / 4;  
  // also possible floor($price * 4) / 4;
  // it depends on your business logic.
}
```

to check how it works try:

`echo round_quarter(131.26);`

Comment: if try bellow eg.

$price = 13.70;
$roundPrice = round($price * 4) / 4;
echo $roundPrice;

Comment: It is totally wrong

Comment: and what is wrong, can you please explain? 13,70*4 =  54.8,  round and get 55, divide and get nearest value of 13.75   If you want to get lower value 13.5 in our case, please use floor() instead of round.